# How to list alphabetically in this way?

Tags: python, alphabetical, names

I have to sort the user inputted names without using the list sort method. this is what i have so far but am having issues with defining 'one' 'two' and 'three'. i need the program to go through each letter to make sure it is truly alphabetical. can anyone help?

```
name1=str(input("Enter name #1: "))
name2=str(input("Enter name #2: "))
name3=str(input("Enter name #3: "))

one = name1[0].upper() + name1[1].upper() + name1[2].upper()
two = name2[0].upper() + name2[1].upper() + name2[2].upper()
three = name3[0].upper() + name3[1].upper() + name3[2].upper()

if one < two and two < three:
     print("These names in alphabetical order are: ", name1, name2, name3)
elif one < two and three < two:
     print("These names in alphabetical order are: ", name1, name3, name2)     
elif two < three and three < one:
     print("These names in alphabetical order are: ", name2, name3, name1)
elif two < one and one < three:
     print("These names in alphabetical order are: ", name2, name1, name3)
elif three < two and two < one:
     print("These names in alphabetical order are: ", name3, name2, name1)
else:
     print("These names in alphabetical order are: ", name3, name1, name2)
```

thanks in advance!
*edit* my issue is in defining 'one' 'two' and 'three' it needs to run through all of the letters in the input. right now it runs through the first three letters but if i add the next letter and only a three letter name is given it errors. and if i use the len function it tells me its an integer

Comment: This smells like homework. Why aren't you allowed to use the "list sort" function? What have you tried so far? What are the problems you've encountered.

Comment: There's a `isalpha` method for testing if a string is truly alphabetical

Comment: What are `one`, `two` and `three` for? Why just compare the first three letters? Also, you could do `one = name1[:3].upper()` or (probably more like what you need) just `one = name1.upper()`. And instead of `one < two and two < three` you can do `one < two < three`. _Also_, from `one < two and three < two`, how do you infer that `name1 < name3`?

Comment: @tobias_k Looks like first, middle, last name are expected, perhaps

Comment: @cricket_007 Possible, but then it's missing a `split()` on all three names.

Comment: @tobias_k Thus the question. "having issues with defining 'one' 'two' and 'three'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i need the program to go through each letter to make sure it is truly alphabetical.

That's what string comparison does anyway. The problem with your code is that you restrict `one`, `two` and `three` to the first three letters of the input strings. Instead, you should just uppercase the *entire* name and compare those.

```
name1 = input("Enter name #1: ")  # no need for str(...)
... # same for name2, name3

one = name1.upper()  # uppercase whole nam, not just first three letters
... # same for two, three

answer = "These names in alphabetical order are: "  # don't repeat this X times
if one < two < three:  # comparison chaining
    print(answer, name1, name2, name3)
elif one < three < two:
    print(answer, name1, name3, name2)
elif ...:
    # a whole bunch more
else:
    print(answer, name3, name2, name1)
```

Comment: this worked perfect. thank you. i think i was too stuck on the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the good old sorting algorithm

```
letters = [name1.upper(),name2.upper(),name3.upper()] 
for i in range(len(letters)):
   for j in range(i,len(letters)):
             if letters[i] > letters[j]:
                     letters[i],letters[j] = letters[j],letters[i]
```

Comment: The variable 'letters' is a list that contains the names in uppercase. In python if you compare two words , it will compare everything. for example the statement `'ABCDE' <  'ABCDF'` yeilds `True`

Comment: Sorry, got so confused by the name `letters` that I did not see that you are uppercasing the entire word. Still, this will require a second pass to find the correct position for the actual names based on the position of the uppercased version. Instead, you could use `letters = [(name1.upper(), name1), ...]` and use the same algo to sort those tuples, then extract the original names.

Comment: Yup that will indeed retain the original names. But I assumed that once the names are all sorted out, the OP would be able to extract the names and did not post a complete solution. Should I edit my answer or leave it that way ? I am new to StackOverflow society.